# CSRF in ReactJS with Express and csurf

Tags: reactjs, express, csrf

I'm looking for a 'nice' way to implement CSRF in ReactJS. So far I've only seen examples where it's used for SSR-apps and where they set an input type like this:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="">
```

This is also possible for React, however, I don't like the fact that you have to copy it around in your codebase.

In the Express docs [they talk](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/csurf.html) about using it in SPA's, however, here they use the `res.render` (which is not used when your frontend uses ReactJS) method like so:

```
app.all('*', function (req, res) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken())
  res.render('index')
})
```

How this be implemented in React?

Comment: It's generally expected that a react app would use ajax rather than standard form submission to post the data to the server. All you need to do is to read the token from the header provided by the server and put it in to the outgoing request header. Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: The comment above does not explain the issue at all.